# Нужно добиться вида ссылки типа app.loc/id1

Tags: php, .htaccess

Здравствуйте, мне нужно добиться ссылки вида, к примеру: app.loc/id1
Но при этом мне нужно считывать сам ID с помощью GET, т.е. нынешний вид  у меня: 
app.loc/?id=1132132

Почитал несколько статей, но не выходит найти нужный пример.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чтобы при обращении по адресу `app.loc/id12345` у вас запускался индексный файл с *GET* параметром `id=12345` достаточно прописать в *.htaccess*

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^id(\d+)$ index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, мсье!